# Making a key binding to travel through Sublime Text 3's buffers (tabs)

Tags: vim, sublimetext3, key-bindings, sublime-text-plugin

I am using `NeoVintageous` package inside `Sublime Text 3` to access `vim/neovim` keybindings. The package has support for remapping my default keys by editing `.neovintageousrc`. I recently mapped `Ctrl-h` and `Ctrl-l` to navigate through splits like this:

```
:nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
:nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

I was wondering if I could navigate through the buffers in somewhat similar fashion. Since `<tab>` is to be remapped here, I am facing some difficulties.
I tried this:

```
:nnoremap L <C-<tab>>
```

I thought this would allow me to move to next buffer similar to what `Ctrl-tab` would do. But this doesn't work. Does anyone happen to know a way to map this?

Comment: If that plugin follows Vim convention for key notation, it should be `<C-Tab>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `gt` command may be what you want:

```
:tabn[ext]              *:tabn* *:tabnext* *gt*
<C-PageDown>                *CTRL-<PageDown>* *<C-PageDown>*
gt                  *i_CTRL-<PageDown>* *i_<C-PageDown>*
        Go to the next tab page.  Wraps around from the last to the
        first one.
```

See `:help gt`.

You can map to that:

```
:nnoremap L gt
```

It looks like the `<C-tab>` is not yet mappable.